# Reload a browser in java

Tags: java, browser, reload

Hi guys I create a browser with this code and now I have to reload the browser (the browser is in my "java window")

```
 final Browser browser = new Browser(shlFreeViews, SWT.NONE);
                browser.setUrl(urls);
                browser.setBounds(10, 366, 888, 214);
```

Answer (score 1):

you have refresh() in org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser, so you can do

```
browser.refresh();
```

to refresh the current page.

Please refer to [this](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fbrowser%2FBrowser.html) link for documentation.

Try something like below for internal browser :

```
browser.addProgressListener(new ProgressAdapter() {
        public void completed(ProgressEvent event) {
            browser.removeProgressListener(this);
            browser.refresh(); 
        }
    });
    browser.setUrl("<url of reload page>");
```

Please refer to [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=300174) issue link for more details